# Converging Sums of a Fractal Sequence

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, number-theory, fractal

### Background

A [fractal sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_sequence) is an integer sequences where you can remove the first occurrence of every integer and end up with the same sequence as before.

A very simple such sequence is called [Kimberling's paraphrases](https://oeis.org/A003602). You start with the positive natural numbers:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...
```

Then you riffle in some blanks:

```
1, _, 2, _, 3, _, 4, _, 5, _, 6, _, 7, _, 8, _, 9, ...
```

And then you repeatedly fill in the blanks with the sequence itself (including the blanks):

```
1, 1, 2, _, 3, 2, 4, _, 5, 3, 6, _, 7, 4, 8, _, 9, ...
1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, _, 5, 3, 6, 2, 7, 4, 8, _, 9, ...
1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 6, 2, 7, 4, 8, _, 9, ...
1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 6, 2, 7, 4, 8, 1, 9, ...
```

That's our fractal sequence! Now let's take the partial sums:

```
1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 14, 15, 20, 23, 29, 31, 38, 42, 50, 51, 60, ...
```

But what if we iterate this process? "Fractalise" the new sequence (i.e. the partial sums obtained from the steps above):

```
1, _, 2, _, 4, _, 5, _, 8, _, 10, _, 14, _, 15, _, 20, _, 23, ...
1, 1, 2, _, 4, 2, 5, _, 8, 4, 10, _, 14, 5, 15, _, 20, 8, 23, ...
1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 5, _, 8, 4, 10, 2, 14, 5, 15, _, 20, 8, 23, ...
1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 8, 4, 10, 2, 14, 5, 15, _, 20, 8, 23, ...
1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 8, 4, 10, 2, 14, 5, 15, 1, 20, 8, 23, ...
```

And take the partial sums again:

```
1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 11, 16, 17, 25, 29, 39, 41, 55, 60, 75, 76, 96, ...
```

Rinse, repeat. It turns out that this process converges. Every time you repeat this process, a larger prefix of the sequence will remain fixed. After an infinite amount of iterations, you would end up with OEIS [A085765](https://oeis.org/A085765).

**Fun fact:** This process would converge to the same sequence even if we didn't start from the natural numbers as long as the original sequence starts with `1`. If the original sequence starts with any other `x`, we'd obtain `x*A085765` instead.

### The Challenge

Given a positive integer `N`, output the `N`th element of the converged sequence.

You may write a program or function, taking input via STDIN (or closest alternative), command-line argument or function argument and outputting the result via STDOUT (or closest alternative), function return value or function (out) parameter.

You may choose whether the index `N` is 0- or 1-based.

### Test Cases

The sequence starts with:

```
1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 11, 16, 17, 26, 30, 41, 43, 59, 64, 81, 82, 108, 117, 147, 151, 192, 203, 246, 248, 307, 323, 387, 392, 473, 490, 572, 573, 681, 707, 824, 833, 980, 1010, 1161, 1165, 1357, 1398, 1601, 1612, 1858, 1901, 2149, 2151, 2458, 2517
```

So input `5` should result in output `9`.

[Here is a naive CJam reference implementation](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri%3AX%2C%3A)%7B%3AL0a*%7B_%7B_%7B%3B(%7D%7C%5C%7D%25W%3C_0%26%7DgX%3C0%5C%7B%2B_%7D%25W%3C_L%3D!%7DgN*&input=1000) which generates the first `N` numbers (given `N` on STDIN). Note that your code should only return the `N`th element, not the entire prefix.

Comment: So just checking: we are outputting the `N`th term of [A085765](https://oeis.org/A085765), correct?

Comment: @GamrCorps Yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### CJam (<strike>23</strike> 22 bytes)

The partial sums are given at the even indexes of the fractal sequence, which is [A086450](https://oeis.org/A086450). The recurrence given there as the definition of A086450 is the basis for these implementations.

Using an explicit "stack" (in scare quotes because it's not LIFO):

```
{),){2md~)\),>+$)}h+,}
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B)%2C)%7B2md~)%5C)%2C%3E%2B%24)%7Dh%2B%2C%7D%0A%0A24%25%60)

#### Dissection

```
{         e# Anonymous function body; for clarify, pretend it's f(x)
          e# We use a stack [x_0 ... x_i] with invariant: the result is sum_j f(x_j)
  ),      e# Initialise the stack to [0 ... x]
  )       e# Uncons x, because our loop wants one value outside the stack
  {       e# Loop. Stack holds [x_0 ... x_{i-1}] x_i
    2md   e# Split x_i into (x_i)/2 and (x_i)%2
    ~)\   e# Negate (x_i)%2 and flip under (x_i)/2
    ),>   e# If x_i was even, stack now holds [x_0 ... x_{i-1}] [0 1 ... (x_i)/2]
          e# If x_i was odd, stack now holds [x_0 ... x_{i-1}] [(x_i)/2]
    +     e# Append the two arrays
    $     e# Sort to get the new stack
    )     e# Uncons the greatest element in the new stack
  }h      e# If it is non-zero, loop
          e# We now have a stack of zeroes and a loose zero
  +,      e# Count the total number of zeroes, which is equivalent to sum_j f(0)
}
```

---

At 23 bytes there's a much more efficient approach, with memoisation:

```
{2*1a{2md~)\){j}%>:+}j}
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B2*1a%7B2md~)%5C)%7Bj%7D%25%3E%3A%2B%7Dj%7D%0A%0A50%25%60)

Comment: I'm sure there are some languages in which it would be shorter to implement as `f(0) = 1; f(n) = f(n/2) + (n % 2 ? 0 : f(n-2)); return f(2*x)`, but I can't find a way to get a saving with that approach in CJam.

Answer (score 9):

## Python 2, <s>55 49</s> 42

I have no idea what's going on, but it seems hard to beat the Maple formula from the OEIS page.
This uses 0-based indexing.

```
f=lambda n,t=0:n<1or f(n/2,n%2)-~-t*f(n-1)
```

Thanks to @PeterTaylor for -6 bytes.

Comment: It's easy to optimise by 6 chars if you don't care about performance. The parts after the first `or` are effectively `g(n,1) = f(n/2,n%2); g(n,0) = f(n-1) + g(n,1)`; so you can pull out the common `g(n,1)` to get `f=lambda n,t=0:n<1or f(n/2,n%2)+0**t*f(n-1)`

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 65

```
s l=[0..]>>=(\i->[l!!i,s l!!i])
r=1:(tail$scanl1(+)$s r)
f n=r!!n
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Templates Considered Harmful](https://github.com/feresum/tmp-lang), 124

```
Fun<If<A<1>,Add<Ap<Fun<Ap<If<Sub<A<1>,Mul<I<2>,Div<A<1>,I<2>>>>,A<0>,A<0,1>>,Div<A<1>,I<2>>>>,A<1>>,Ap<A<0>,Sub<A<1>,T>>>,T>>
```

This is an anonymous function. It's more or less the same as  <s>my Python answer</s> the Maple formula on the OEIS page, except that I didn't implement modulus, so I had to use n-n/2*2 instead of n%2.

Expanded:

```
Fun<If<
    A<1>,
    Add<
        Ap<
            Fun<Ap<
                If<
                    Sub<
                        A<1>,
                        Mul<
                            I<2>,
                            Div<A<1>,I<2> >
                        >
                    >,
                    A<0>,
                    A<0,1>
                >,
                Div<A<1>,I<2>>
            >>,
            A<1>
        >,
        Ap<
            A<0>,
            Sub<A<1>, T>
        >
    >,
    T
>>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>47</s> 44 bytes

```
If[#<1,1,#0[Floor@#/2]+(1-2#~Mod~1)#0[#-1]]&
```

Answer (score 0):

## Matlab <s>108</s> 103

I am using the fact that the desired series is the partial sum of https://oeis.org/A086450

But the computation complexity of my implementation is far from optimal, even for this simple recurrence.

```
n=input('')+1;
z=zeros(1,n);z(1)=1;
for k=1:n;
z(2*k)=z(k);
z(2*k+1)=sum(z(1:k+1));
end;
disp(sum(z(1:n)))
```